# working with 3 $_GET values

Tags: php, get

I have a problem with $_GET array. On my page a value comes from URL like this.

```
http://localhost/search.php?subject=Mathematics
```

I check this $_GET value something like this..

```
// Check for a valid keyword from search input:
if ( (isset($_GET['subject'])) && (is_string ($_GET['subject'])) ) { // From SESSION
    foreach ( $_GET AS $key => $subject) {
        $searchKey = $key;
        $searchKeyword = '%'.$subject.'%';
    }

} else { // No valid keyword, kill the script.
    echo 'This page has been accessed in error.';
    include ('includes/footer.html');
    exit();
}
```

Now its working for me. But my problem is I am using another two variables to pass through URL on same page to filter my database values.

```
echo '<li><a href="?tutor=link">Tutor</a></li>
      <li><a href="?institute=link">Institute</a></li>';
```

This two links I used to filter my database values (clicking on this link).

```
$tutor = isset($_GET['institute']) ? '0' : '1'; 
$institute = isset($_GET['tutor']) ? '0' : '1';
```

My problem is when I am trying filter database result clicking on the above link its always going this code instead of displaying filtered result.

```
} else { // No valid keyword, kill the script.
    echo 'This page has been accessed in error.';
    include ('includes/footer.html');
    exit();
}
```

Can anybody tell me how I use this 3 $_GET values.

Comment: Why not TWO query parameters? `target=tutor&link=...`? That reduces you to checking if `$_GET['target']` contains something valid, instead of having to check three different possible $_GET values.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a clause in the `else`:

```
elseif(!isset($_GET['institute']) && !isset($_GET['tutor'])) 
{
    echo 'This page has been accessed in error.';
    include ('includes/footer.html');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the url looks like this:

```
http://localhost/search.php?subject=Mathematics&tutor=tutorName&institute=instituteName
```

A `?` denotes the beginning of the URL parameters, an `&` marks the separation between url parameters

Comment: yes I tried it with changing my links like this -   echo '<li><a href="?subject='.$subject.'&tutor=link">Tutor</a></li>
    <li><a href="?subject='.$subject.'&institute=link">Institute</a></li>';

Comment: and also changed this code to -  $tutor = isset($_GET['subject']) && isset($_GET['institute']) ? '0' : '1'; 
 $institute = isset($_GET['subject']) && isset($_GET['tutor']) ? '0' : '1';

Comment: You have institute and tutor the wrong way round in that snippet

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are only checking the $_GET['subject'] variable, which is no being passed in.  You could do this in a few ways, all resulting in changing:

```
if ( (isset($_GET['subject'])) && (is_string ($_GET['subject'])) ) { // From SESSION
```

1) include all variables in the conditional string:

```
if ( ((isset($_GET['subject'])) && (is_string ($_GET['subject']))) || ((isset($_GET['institute'])) && (is_string ($_GET['institute']))) || ((isset($_GET['tutor'])) && (is_string ($_GET['tutor']))) ) {
```

2) Pass in searchKey=1 or something in all your links and use:

```
if ( isset($_GET['searchKey']) ) { // From SESSION
```

Revised links:

```
echo '<li><a href="?searchKey=1&amp;tutor=link">Tutor</a></li>
      <li><a href="?searchKey=1&amp;institute=link">Institute</a></li>';
```

If you are looking to pass in more than one variable at once, you will need to put the search keys into an array.

Comment: I am not clear about this : Pass in searchKey=1 or something in all your calls and use: Can you elaborate it with an example?

Comment: Just revised my example, but think #2 is more of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't seem to be, that you're running into the `else` loop (or better said: not the *only* problem). It looks like your first parameter gets lost with the second link. I think, the second link should react like some kind of extended search filter, that shoud be applied to the recently displayed content, or am I totally wrong at understanding you?

Perhaps this could solve your problem for creating the follow-up URLs.

```
$params = array();

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
  $params[] = '&'.$key.'='.$value;
}

$url1 = '?tutor=link'.implode('', $params);
$url2 = '?institute=link'.implode('', $params);
```

And when you output the links:

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$url1.'">Tutor</a></li>
      <li><a href="'.$url2.'">Institute</a></li>';
```